# Python-Requests Post Status Error (HTTP/0.9)

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am currently involved in a project where it is necessary to send POST requests to a remote server. I have noticed unexpected behavior when trying to emulate a POST request that I receive from Mozilla Firefox.

Specifically, when I perform the POST request through Mozilla Firefox, I receive a response with HTTP/0.9 without headers and a reported status of 200. However, when I try to emulate the same POST request in Python 3 using the requests library, I do not receive any status code, and I encounter an error:

```
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<html><body>\n'))
```

After a more in-depth analysis, I discovered that the server is responding with HTTP/0.9, which may be the cause of the problem. However, I am unable to obtain a valid status code using requests.

My request header is as follows:

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "Accept": "application/xhtml+xml",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, bz"}
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests

uid = "3491282510"url = f'https://10.97.80.44/goform/formPostData?LE=ethPortCfg&UID={uid}'print(url)

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
"Accept": "application/xhtml+xml",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, bz"}

data = {
'fd0': '0/2',
'fd1': 'Port 2',
'fd2': '0/2',
'fd3': '1000X',
'fd4': 'Disabled',
'fd5': 'On',
'fd6': '1G',
'fd7': 'Full',
'fd8': 'Off',
'fd9': 'Off',
'fd10': 'On',
'fd11': 'Do nothing',
'fd12': 'N/A',
'fd13': '5',
'choice': 'Apply'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
```

To temporarily resolve the issue, I modified the behavior of the `_read_status(self)` function in the requests library to convert the first line into a valid status code. I also simulated the presence of the line `line = b'\r\n'` in the function `parse_headers()` to avoid issues when trying reading the headers.

How can I correctly interpret the response from the server without modifying client.py?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP/0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) is a one-line, `GET`-only protocol. It strikes me as odd your server would respond with that in this day and age, but I also have no idea what your server is or isn't doing.

Try sending some `POST`s through a Chromium-based browser and something like PostMan as well I suppose, as maybe the server is just reporting the wrong protocol and sending the correct kind of data, in which case you should contact the server admin to resolve this.

For reference: requests [stopped accepting HTTP/0.9](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/updates/#id62) nearly a decade ago for Python 2.x. [The PR in question](https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/2323) mentions the Python 3 version ceased support for it earlier than that. Python stdlib also [dropped it in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection) and I can't find *anything* for Python that does still offer support for it.